# nvm node.js use version not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I am trying to install node.js using NVM tool ([LINK to NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm))

I have Linux Mint 17 cinnamon

I have follower instructions  on nvm page and everything went fine except when I run :

```
nvm use 0.10
```

it works while I am logged in on computer. When I restart computer I cannot access node shell in termninal (it says I need to install node with apt-get etc) and it works again only when I type **nvm use** which is annoying.

Is this normal behaviour or I am doing something wrong or there is some other problem?

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Hm ... now I repeated the procedure and it is working. Strange, maybe something else affected this and maybe this is false alarm. For now I will assume it is working until I manage to reproduce it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, but you can put `nvm use 0.10` in `.bashrc` to avoid typing it all the time.